# Twitter APIを利用したソーシャルログインで認証許可後にログインが行えていない

Tags: laravel, twitter, laravel-5

### 現在の問題

Twitter APIを利用してTwitterアカウントでログインを出来るようにしたいと考えております。
現在発生している問題はTwitterの認証画面が表示され、認証を許可するところまでは良いのですが、自作サイトに移動するとログインが出来ていないというのが問題になっております。

DBも確認してみましたが、登録がされていない状態でしたので、登録の処理が出来ていないので、ログインが出来ていないと考えており、スペルミス等を可能な限り確認しましたが、まだ原因はわかっておりません。

どの部分を重点的に確認すれば良いかなどアドバイスをいただけると幸いです。

以下のサイトを参考に作成しました。

[laravel Auth Twitter 連携 - Qiita](https://qiita.com/ma7ma7pipipi/items/5cd58f0966ab1bc44a31#%E3%83%86%E3%83%BC%E3%83%96%E3%83%AB%E4%BD%9C%E6%88%90)

## 現環境

- さくらサーバー
- PHP:7.4.7
- MySQL:5.7
- Laravel:5.8
- socialite:4.0

---

**app/Http/Controllers/Auth/OAuthLoginController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Social;
use Socialite;

class OAuthLoginController extends Controller
{
public function getTwitterAuth()
{
    return Socialite::driver('twitter')->redirect();
}

public function authTwitterCallback()
{
  $data = Socialite::driver('twitter')->user();

  $res = Social::query()
      ->where('id',$data->id)
      ->get();

  if(!empty($res[0]->user->id)){
      //ログインしている場合
      Auth::login($res[0]->user);
      return redirect('/')->with('status', 'ログインしました');
  } else {
      //まだログインしたことない場合 情報をセッションに保存し新規会員登録へ
      session(['twitter' => $data]);
      return redirect('register')->with('status', 'Twitter連携しました');
  }
 }
}
```

**app/Http/Controllers/Auth/RegisterController.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Social;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Register Controller
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
| validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
| provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
|
*/

use RegistersUsers;

/**
 * Where to redirect users after registration.
 *
 * @var string
 */
protected $redirectTo = '/shares';

/**
 * Create a new controller instance.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('guest');
}

/**
 * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
 */
protected function validator(array $data)
{
    return Validator::make($data, [
        // 追加
        'screen_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'name'        => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
        'email'       => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
        'password'    => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
    ]);
}

/**
 * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
 *
 * @param  array  $data
 * @return \App\Models\User
 */
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        // 追加
        'screen_name' => $data['screen_name'],
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
    ]);

    if(session('twitter')){

        $social = session('twitter');

        Social::create([
            'id' => $social->id,
            'user_id' => $res->id,
            'name' => $social->name,
            'screen_name' => $social->nickname,
            'verified' => $social->user['verified'],
            'token' => $social->token,
            'token_secret' => $social->tokenSecret,
            'img' => $social->avatar,
            'profile_banner_url' => $social->user['profile_banner_url'],
            'profile_image_url_https' => $social->user['profile_image_url_https'],
            'expired' => 0
        ]);

        session()->forget('twitter');
    }

    return $res;
 }
}
```

Comment: 確認です: 提示記事で示されている(そして実装されている)のは「Twitter認証」→「ユーザー情報入力」→「登録」のようですが，認識はあってますか？ / `User::create` に `screen_name` を追加されているようですが，これはフォームで入力させるものですか？ / 登録の処理ができていない，ということですが実際にどのような挙動になっているかわかりますか？なんらかのエラーが出たりしてリダイレクトしていますか？そもそもその部分にたどり着いていますか？ログやdebugbar，レスポンス(devtoolなどで確認できる)なども確認してみてください

Comment: コメントいただきありがとうございます。
「Twitter認証」→「ユーザー情報入力」→「登録」の手順の認識であっております。
User::create screen_name についてはフォームで入力させる項目となります。
レスポンスについて確認してみます。

Comment: 今気づいたのですが通常のアカウント登録も出来ない状態になってるので、もしかしたらそれに起因してるのかもと考えております。

Comment: 例えば、screen_nameがDBで必須になっていてかつfillableに追加されていない、等では生じる気はしますが、その場合は別途エラーが出そうですね（？）

Comment: レスポンスについてですがdevtoolsを使用して確認いたしました。
devtoolsの機能を始めて利用したのであっているか不安ですが、
[Network]タブでname:authorize(https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authorize) のstatus codeが200であることを確認いたしました。
500のサーバーエラーはありませんでした。
(見る場所が違うなどご指摘あればご教示いただけないでしょうか。)

Comment: fillable についてDBと見比べて確認してみます！